# Logstash - Is it possible to create a java program for logstash

Tags: java, logstash

I need to create a java program for generating logstash output accouding to some configurations (conf file). But here my problem is i have the configurations in a Properties object also i need the output as a Json String object. But in [examples](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash) i found from internet it will do like, need to run the command following through console and the output become appear on the console

```
logstash -f config.conf
```

But i need a java program instead of the above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use logstash at all to insert data into elasticsearch.  You can do it directly from [java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/index.html) and use the [index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-index.html).

Comment: the above links are broken

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Java program in a following way.

1. Create your logstash configuration file and place it anywhere in your file system.
2. Ensure that you can execute this file using logstash -f yourfile.conf.
3. Now write a java program to execute this logstsah file.

Sample code to execute linux command from java code :

```
public void executeLinux(String command) {
        System.out.println("Executing linux command "+command);

        try{
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = run.exec(command);
            pr.waitFor();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok,the logstash2.x has supported read config file from http , ftp and so on.

for example :
`java
bin/logstash -f http://xx.xx.xx/xx.config  --auto-reload --reload-interval 2`

click here ""[The Logstash Lines: 2.2 Release, Dynamic Config Reloading](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-lines-2016-02-09)

and here [Apply changes from configuration file without restarting](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/4513)

you can dynamically  create config file in java project,and put redis,and the logstash load config file from springmvc's controller.